# How to add a dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged event to UpdatePanel triggers programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a dropdowlist added programmatically like this:

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.ID = my_id;
ddl.AutoPostBack = true; // I've also tried to remove this line 
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += Index_Changed;
bdy.Controls.Add(ddl);
```

So then I want to add its event to my update panel trigger, I tried:

```
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger() { ControlID = ddl.ID, EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged" });
```

and also:

```
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger() { ControlID = ddl.UniqueID, EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged" });
```

but nothing works; although I have linkbutton click event trigger works fine like this

```
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger() { ControlID = linkbtn.UniqueID, EventName = "Click" });
```

So how can I add its event to my update panel trigger?

Comment: Curious to know how you are sure it is not working.

Comment: Try removing the event name. i don't think it's required.